# Given an array of dates, display results within groupings of "week of" ranges

Tags: javascript

I need to display the "week of" range that a list of dates falls within. For example, given an array of dates:

```
const dates = [
  '2019-11-15', 
  '2019-11-13', 
  '2019-11-12', 
  '2019-11-09', 
  '2019-11-05', 
  '2019-11-03', 
  '2019-10-31', 
  '2019-10-28'
];
```

I need to output:

Week of 11/10-11/16:

- 2019-11-15
- 2019-11-13
- 2019-11-12

Week of 11/3-11/9:

- 2019-11-09
- 2019-11-05
- 2019-11-03

Week of 10/27-11/2:

- 2019-10-31
- 2019-10-28

I'm struggling with approaching how to generate the proper ranges for each week (sun-sat). The ranges need to be limited to the range of all of the dates in the array; i.e. no empty "week of" ranges before or after the ones needed for the given list of dates.

Comment: pass date ranges and use https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/ method

Comment: I was looking at this earlier. Wouldn't I need to know that start and end date for each week in order to compare a given date against?

Comment: I was thinking about getting the week num for a given date, then getting its day num.  From there, subtracting/adding days in order to reach the limits of a given week.

Comment: What is the definition for `Week of 10/27-11/2:`?

Comment: Sunday through Saturday each week.

Comment: r u using moment js ?

Comment: No, I am trying to limit library use, but can use it if it makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plain JS:

```js
var dates = ['2019-11-15', '2019-11-13', '2019-11-12', '2019-11-09', '2019-11-05', '2019-11-03', '2019-10-31', '2019-10-28'], result = {};

function formatDate(date)
{
    var day = "0"+date.getDate(), month = "0"+(date.getMonth()+1);
    return [month.slice(-2), day.slice(-2)].join("/");
}
dates.forEach(function(d){
    var date = new Date(d), day = date.getDay();
    var start = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()-day));
    var end = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+6));
    var range = formatDate(start)+"-"+formatDate(end);
    if(!result[range]) result[range] = [];
    result[range].push(d);
});
console.log(result)
```

Using [moment.js - startOf, endOf](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)

```js
var dates = ['2019-11-15', '2019-11-13', '2019-11-12', '2019-11-09', '2019-11-05', '2019-11-03', '2019-10-31', '2019-10-28'], result = {};

dates.forEach(function(date){
    var m = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    var range = m.startOf('week').format('Y/M/D')+'-'+m.endOf('week').format('Y/M/D');
    if(!result[range]) result[range] = [];
    result[range].push(date);
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For the plain JS version, I had to drop the year from the date format in order for it to display correctly: return [month.slice(-2), day.slice(-2)].join("/");

Comment: The plain JS version is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using [startOf](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [endOf](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) week

```js
var dates = ['2019-11-15', '2019-11-13', '2019-11-12', '2019-11-09', '2019-11-05', '2019-11-03', '2019-10-31', '2019-10-28']

const result = dates.reduce((a, i) => {
  let m = moment(i)
  let k = m.startOf('week').format('M/D') + '-' + m.endOf('week').format('M/D')
  a[k] = (a[k] || []).concat(i)
  return a
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excellent solution!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dates = [
  '2019-11-15',
  '2019-11-13',
  '2019-11-12',
  '2019-11-09',
  '2019-11-05',
  '2019-11-03',
  '2019-10-31',
  '2019-10-28'
];

let gp = {};
for(let i=0; i<dates.length; i++){
  let dt = moment(dates[i]);
  let week = dt.startOf('week').format('M/D') + '-' + dt.endOf('week').format('M/D');
  if(gp[week]){
    gp[week].push(dates[i]);
  }else{
    gp[week] = [dates[i]];
  }
}

console.log(gp)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a logic that does it. Here's a code for you:

```
const dates = [
  '2019-11-15', 
  '2019-11-13', 
  '2019-11-12', 
  '2019-11-09', 
  '2019-11-05', 
  '2019-11-03', 
  '2019-10-31', 
  '2019-10-28'
];

//call on console..      printRange(dates,13,31);

function printRange(array,date1,date2){
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){

        var str = array[i].substring(8,10);
        if(str>=date1 && str<=date2)console.log(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution uses pure javascript and the `reduce()` function:

each cycle:

1. get the previous and current dates and days of the week
2. get the difference in days between the previous and current date
3. if the diff is > 7, add the current date into a new array, otherwise, push it to the end of the previous array

```js
const dates = [
  '2019-11-15', 
  '2019-11-13', 
  '2019-11-12', 
  '2019-11-09', 
  '2019-11-05', 
  '2019-11-03', 
  '2019-10-31', 
  '2019-10-28'
]

const weeks = dates.reverse().reduce((acc,cur) => {
    //Part 1
    const recentWeek = acc[acc.length-1] || []
    const prevDate = new Date(recentWeek[recentWeek.length-1] || "0000-00-00")
    const prevDay = prevDate.getUTCDay()
    if(!prevDate){
        return acc.concat(acc,[cur])
    }
    const curDate = new Date(cur)
    const curDay = curDate.getUTCDay()

    //Part 2
    const diffTime = Math.abs(curDate - prevDate);
    const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    //Part 3
    if(curDay > prevDay && diffDays < 7){
        recentWeek.push(cur)
        acc.pop()
        acc.push(recentWeek)
    }else{
        acc.push([cur])
    }
    
    return acc
},[]).reverse().map(el => el.reverse())

console.log(weeks)
```

Comment: The grouping is correct, but I'm not seeing the "week of" range before each grouping. I saw it, or something close to it, when you first posted your solution. I thought it was closer before you edited it.